# Coding trade data to be directed

Tags: r, direction

I want to create a trade map (import data) between Africa and the world in R. Essentially I only have 4 variables laid out as in the table below (for about 14.000 observations). Import1 and Import2 are the two nations trading, where flow1 is the imports of import1 from import2 and flow2 is the imports of import2 from import1.

```
import1 import2 flow1 flow2

Algeria Tunisia   113.96    130.01

Algeria Libya     1.966 11.19

Algeria Sudan     0.0165   0
```

What I can't figure out is how to get R to read flow1 as the direction from import2 --> import1 and flow2 as trade direction import1 --> import2. Just looking for some guidance on how to code this part in R as I really have no been able to find anything that helps online as of yet. Thank you!

I've made a dataframe with the 4 variables but it just uses import1 and import2 and thinks that import1-->import2 is the connection.

```
df1 <- Trade_Data %>% 
       filter(year == 2003) %>% 
       select(importer1, importer2, flow1, flow2)
df1 <-df1[!(df1$flow1== 0 & df1$flow2==0),]
View(df1)
g1 <- graph.data.frame(df1, directed = T)
g1
```

I expect the output to be Algeria <-->Tunisia (for example), but the output is actually Algeria --> Tunisia.

Comment: A couple of questions, first you went from import1 import2 to importer1 importer2 .... is that a typo or did something happen?   Also I would suggest either use dplyr for your filtering or use the [] notation -- be consistent and it will make your code easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example from the graph.data.frame help file.

```
actors <- data.frame(name=c("Alice", "Bob", "Cecil", "David",
                            "Esmeralda"),
                     age=c(48,33,45,34,21),
                     gender=c("F","M","F","M","F"))
relations <- data.frame(from=c("Bob", "Cecil", "Cecil", "David",
                               "David", "Esmeralda"),
                        to=c("Alice", "Bob", "Alice", "Alice", "Bob", "Alice"),
                        same.dept=c(FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE),
                        friendship=c(4,5,5,2,1,1), advice=c(4,5,5,4,2,3))
g <- graph_from_data_frame(relations, directed=TRUE, vertices=actors)
```

yielding these edges

```
+ edges from 3d02353 (vertex names):
[1] Bob      ->Alice Cecil    ->Bob   Cecil    ->Alice David    ->Alice David    ->Bob  
[6] Esmeralda->Alice
```

As you can see, in your code you have not created a vertices array but what you have done is create two relations.

Especially in a directed graph, you can't take the short cut of combining all the data into the same row if you actually want to know that the relations go in opposite ways.

What I'd suggest you do is to move to a long format with each directed edge (from, to) as a separate row and then put the flow in the row with the appropriate direction.

I'd also suggest using more descriptive column names such as "exporter" "importer" or "from" "to"  since import1 and import2 doesn't really provide  enough self contained information to know what they are.

Alternatively, if you really want to express this as two different relations with Algeria (import_from, export_to) then you could do that also. But in that case it will always show the Algeria --> x  relationship